# Confusion Concerning Arbitrary Neighborhoods, Boundary Points, and Isolated Points

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I've been using Steven R. Lay's book, *Analysis with an Introduction to Proof* as a self-study for real analysis. I thought I understood the definitions of a neighborhood (that contains its center), a deleted neighborhood, and then Lay's shift towards an arbitrary neighborhood (the neighborhood could either be one that contains its center as one of its members or not), but based on the following excerpt and a problem that I'm stuck on, I'm not sure if I do understand these concepts as well as I initially thought.

After defining the ideas of a neighborhood $N(x;\epsilon) = (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ and a deleted neighborhood $N^*(x;\epsilon) = N(x;\epsilon)-\{x\}$, he writes

> If for every neighborhood $N$ of $x$, $N\cap S \neq \varnothing$ and $N \cap (\mathbb{R}-S) \neq \varnothing$, then $x$ is called a boundary point of $S$ [, where $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$].

*brackets are mine*

This is the first instance where he mentions an arbitrary neighborhood $N$, and I always thought that $N$ could either be $N(x;\epsilon)$ or $N^*(x;\epsilon)$. Thus, a statement concerning every neighborhood, in my mind, would pertain to both $N(x;\epsilon)$ and $N^*(x;\epsilon)$, like the definition of a boundary point.

Thus, is it possible that my understanding is not correct? That is, for example, could a point $x$ be a boundary point if an arbitrary $N(x;\epsilon)$ satisfies the definition of a boundary point, but for some $\delta > 0$, the deleted neighborhood $N^*(x;\delta)$ does not? Another example might be if $x$ is an isolated point, then $x$ is a boundary point, because every $N(x;\epsilon)$ satisfies the definition, whereas there are some deleted neighborhoods that do not. Or if a statement includes every neighborhood it actually means *every* neighborhood?

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Thank you

Comment: This is actually I think somewhat a misleading definition. A deleted neighborhood, $N^*(x, \epsilon)$, although being "a" neighborhood (in the sense that it is an open set), is not technically a neighborhood of $x$. For $\mathbb{R}$, which is your interest, an (open) neighborhood of $x$ is of the form $U=\bigcup_{i}N(y_i,\epsilon_i)$ for some points $y_i$ and some radii $\epsilon_i$ such that $x\in U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Lay's text, but the standard definition uses neighborhoods (which include their center).  That is almost certainly the intended meaning here.

The only difference between using a neighborhood or a deleted neighborhood is when $S$ contains an isolated point or its complement does.  If $S$ consists of a single point $p \in \mathbb{R}$, then $p$ belongs to the boundary of $S$ using the standard interpretation.  Using deleted neighborhoods instead would imply that $p$ does not belong to the boundary of $S$, since no deleted neighborhood of $p$ meets $S$.

It should also be mentioned that a common definition of a neighborhood of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a set $N$ that contains $N(x,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.  But this may not be the definition used in Lay's text.

Comment: He mentions the common definition of a neighborhood in a footnote, and he says that we "shall not need this more general notion." 

If I'm understanding your second paragraph correctly, it is possible that a point $x$ could be a boundary point for every neighborhood, but not necessarily deleted neighborhoods? In other words, if we wanted to be consistent with the definition I provided in the excerpt where "every neighborhood of $x$", we could interpret this to mean, every neighborhood that includes its center, every deleted neighborhood, or both?

Comment: An important point is that "deleted neighborhood of $x$" is a single term.  It is decidedly *not* a neighborhood of $x$ with the property of being "deleted".  Indeed, a deleted neighborhood of $x$ is not a neighborhood of $x$ at all, as Hamed points out.

Comment: Then I wonder why Lay would define neighborhood using the notation $N(x;\epsilon)$, but then use $N$ instead in some parts, and then revert to $N(x;\epsilon)$ in other parts.

Comment: Here is an example of Lay using $N$ with a proof concerning a set $S$ being closed iff it contains its accumulation points: "Thus there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}-S$ [...]". But then the same proof, he says, "Since $x\notin S$, the whole neighborhood $N(x;\epsilon)$ misses $S$; that is, $N(x;\epsilon) \subseteq \mathbb{R} - S$, my point being that he interchanges between the two notations, so he intentionally has a meaning for each of them.

Comment: From the definition in the excerpt, do you think he is only talking about neighborhoods that contain their centers?